# iOS App Development - autofill service missing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight, autofill

I have created an iOS mobile application (XCode / Swift) that is built with 2 main targets:

- application itself
- application extension (Autofill Service - similar to LastPass for example).

Having said that, when I build or archive only the application is deployed, and in XCode I have to build twice (one for each target) for both the application and the service to work. ( autofill service is missing.)

In terms of what already has been done:

- Verified that deployment target for both is iOS 16.0
- Autofill target is marked as a dependency in the main application target
- When running the Autofill service scheme - both targets are installed on the emulator - however when deploying to TestFlight - once again the autofill service is missing.

Thanks in advance!